# Is pre-increment atomic?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

Question in title. Is it?

Cause pre-increment just adds to the value, so I suppose it is only 1 instruction (not sure if that instruction takes a single cycle too, though).

Post-increment loads the value into a temporary copy, adds to it and then stores back.

Is pre-increment therefore atomic??

Haven't tried anything yet, just a question.

Comment: I suppose the shortest answer is "no": it's a slight variation on the same steps as a post-increment

Comment: Compiling to a single x86 instruction doesn't make it atomic, except on a uniprocessor machine or in a single-threaded process.  Pre vs. post increment only compile differently if you use the result anyway, in which case you'll get `lock xadd` on an atomic type, otherwise just `lock add`.  And if the type isn't atomic, the compiler will probably keep the value in a register unless that's all you're doing with it.  Anyway, see the linked duplicate why why the answer is very much no, regardless of misconceptions about how it might compile (check https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: whether it is atomic in hardware is secondary when the language standard does not give that guarantee

Comment: As far as the C Standards are concerned, it is not only not atomic, it is sort of the opposite of atomic, in that `++i + ++i` is undefined.  Not only is the update not tied to the access, it can be almost arbitrarily far removed from the access.

Comment: Ultimately it depends on the hardware and the assembly code your compiler outputs.